# Powershell not sorting by Name

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to sort the hashtable by Name.

This is the hashtable

```
$hashtable = @{}
$hashtable.Add('16',  'Name = $4 000 000,Value = $4 000 000');
$hashtable.Add('5','Name = $600 000Value = $600 000');
$hashtable.Add('12','Name = $1 750 000;Value = $1 750 000');
$hashtable.Add('10','Name = $1 200 000;Value = $1 200 000');
$hashtable.Add('2','Name = $300 000;Value = $300 000');
$hashtable.Add('8','Name = $900 000;Value = $900 000');
$hashtable.Add('17','Name = $4 000 000;Value = $4 000 000');
$hashtable.Add('11','Name = $1 500 000;Value = $1 500 000');
$hashtable.Add('1','Name = $1000000;Value = $200 000');
$hashtable.Add('9','Name = $1 000 000;Value = $1 000 000');
$hashtable.Add('14','Name = $2 500 000;Value = $2 500 000');
$hashtable.Add('7','Name = $800 000;Value = $800 000');
$hashtable.Add('15','Name = $3 000 000;Value = $3 000 000');
$hashtable.Add('6','Name = $700 000;Value = $700 000');
$hashtable.Add('4','Name = $500 000;Value = $500 000');
$hashtable.Add('13','Name = $2 000 000;Value = $2 000 000');

$hashtable.GetEnumerator() | sort -Property name
```

I have used `$hashtable.GetEnumerator() | sort -Property name` to sort by Name but its not sorting.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What PowerShell version are you using? You currently have 2 different ones tagged. The `Name` property is the `Keys` property when unrolled. Is that what you want to sort by, or you want to sort by the values? What should be the expected result?

Comment: what do you mean by `Name` property, there is no `Name` property on a hashtable. Only `Keys` and `Values`

Comment: I want to sort by Keys

Comment: @Santiago, the hashtable _entries_ have `.Kay` and `.Value` properties, and PowerShell defines `.Name` as an alias property (not sure if it's always been there).

Comment: `$hashtable.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object { [int] $_.Key }` should do it but I dont see the point on this, hashtables are not supposed to be ordered nor ordering them will give you any advantange. Maybe you're looking for an ordered dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a Hashtable with numeric Keys and as Value strings like `Name = Something; Value = Something` (and sometimes the `;` is a `,`) in there..

My guess is you want an array of **objects** instead where each object has 3 properties: an Id, Name and Value  (although in your sample data I don't understand why `Name` would be a currency value like `Value`)

By creating such an object array you can sort on any of the properties.

As example I have rewritten your Hashtable declaration to become a CSV formatted string where I have taken the liberty of changing the property names to `Id`, `Price` and `Value`

```
$table = @'
Id,Price,Value
16,$4 000 000,$4 000 000
5,$600 000,$600 000
12,$1 750 000,$1 750 000
10,$1 200 000,$1 200 000
2,$300 000,$300 000
8,$900 000,$900 000
17,$4 000 000,$4 000 000
11,$1 500 000,$1 500 000
1,$1000000,$200 000
9,$1 000 000,$1 000 000
14,$2 500 000,$2 500 000
7,$800 000,$800 000
15,$3 000 000,$3 000 000
6,$700 000,$700 000
4,$500 000,$500 000
13,$2 000 000,$2 000 000
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Now you can sort anyway you like, for instance:

```
# sort on the `Id` column
$table | Sort-Object {[int]$_.Id}

# sort on the `Price` column 
$table | Sort-Object {[int64]($_.Price -replace '\D')}
```

etc.